# What does it mean for a Gamma distribution to have index $\alpha$ and index $\lambda$

Tags: probability, statistics

I have two easy questions:

1- How is he form of the density of a Gamma distribution with index $\alpha$ and parameter$\lambda$?

2-And if it says "Gamma distribution of mean $a$ and index $b$"?

I know the form of a Gamma distribution but I always hear Gamma with parameters $a$ and $b$, but never heard about this kind of description of Gamma.
Could anybody help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Speculation: $\alpha$ is the shape parameter and $\lambda$ is the rate parameter. Perhaps see [_This Wikipedia page_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), second parameterization, where their $\beta$ may be your $\lambda.$ If so the mean of your first gamma distribution is $\alpha/\lambda.$